# Re enable Windows Authetication in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

My old employee has disabled Windows Authentication in our server. Now I'm not able to access the SQL Server even though I have Administrator access to the server. I need to reset the sa password.

I tried logging in using single user mode as Remus described but I get the following error:

> Login failed for user 'SERVER\Administrator'. 
>   
> Reason: The account is disabled. 
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18470)

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/

Comment: @aaron Thanks. Learn something new everyday. Question, I did some test and if NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SQL login is also disabled/deleted, is there still any way around?

Comment: @Travis not with PSEXEC I don't think; you'll need to use a different workaround.

Comment: @aaron OK, at least we know the MDF/LDF files copy solution to make sure nobody get screwed.

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar There is one more option that I can think of. After querying `sys.server_principals` joined with `sys.server_role_members` I realized that there are 2 more `sysadmin`s in my server: the accounts used by the services `MSSQLSERVER` and `SQLSERVERAGENT`. You can use `services.msc` or the configuration manager to find what user name your services are using, and then find a way to impersonate them.

Answer (score 5):

Follow the steps in:

[Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx).

Briefly:

1. Start server with the `-m` switch
2. Connect as  a local administrator
3. Enable the `sa` account (and reset its password if necessary)
4. Restart server normally

Answer (score 4):

Based on feedback in the comments on this answer, the situation is this:

- There is an explicitly-created `BUILTIN\Administrators` group login in SQL Server that has been denied `CONNECT` to the database engine.
- There is no other `sysadmin`-level login available, including the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` login that gets created by default.

SQL Server does not allow a user to *disable* the `BUILTIN\Administrators` login, but it *can* still be denied `CONNECT`. I consider this a bug, as it's obvious that the inability to disable the login outright was hard-coded into the engine to avoid scenarios like this.

I'm unable to get in after applying that permission.

You will have to either find a way to edit the contents of the `master` database to get rid of the `DENY` permission (totally unsupported, and at your own peril), reinstall the database engine from the installation media, or I suppose you could attempt to brute-force the `sa` password.

I don't believe you can simply rebuild `master` as that requires connecting and authenticating against the database engine, which isn't available here.

Comment: Logged in as newly created admin but unable to access sql account since BuilIn Users/Administrators doesn't have access to MSSQL Server.

Comment: Lovely. Okay, I'll have to work on that. Did you try one of the methods on my blog? If someone has gone to the extent of locking out `BUILTIN\Administrators` (bad idea, by the way), the system account login is probably gone, too, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: ya. can't connect login in anyway... Login failed for user 'SERVER\Administrator'. Reason: The account is disabled. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18470)

Comment: This is interesting. For testing, I added a `BUILTIN\Administrators` login to my instance, which succeeded. I tried to disable it, but it wouldn't let me. I was able to `DENY CONNECT`, however, and this gives me the same error message. Now... to try and fix it.

Answer (score 3):

When  all windows user accounts with sysadmin role  or sa account are disabled in SQL server then how to access the instance?

Below are the steps to solve this problem:

1. Stop existing instance of SQL Server on which all windows user accounts or sa account are disabled
2. Start SQL Server instance in single user mode with following steps

   2.1 Open command prompt in admin mode

   2.2 Run command ( I am running SQL Server 2012 instance)

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL2012\MSSQL\Binn>sqlservr.exe -s 
   SQL2012 –m
   ```
3. Open another command prompt in admin mode
4. Connect to the SQL Server instance using command

   ```
   C:>sqlcmd –S(local)\instancename –E
   ```
5. Create login

   ```
   C:> CREATE LOGIN [loginname] FROM WINDOWS;
   C:>go
   ```
6. Add login to sysadmin role

   ```
   C:> ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [loginname]
   ```
7. Now disconnect from SQL Server instance
8. Stop SQL Server instance by pressing cntl+C and `‘Y’`
9. Start SQL Server instance in multi-user mode and now you will be able to connect using newly created login

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to second the service account suggestion made by Justicator.  If that doesn't work...

This is a long shot, but are you able to do something like this?

- [Leveraging Service SIDs to Logon to SQL Server 2012+ Instances with Sysadmin Privileges](https://www.0xsql.com/2012/01/12/leveraging-service-sids-to-logon-to-sql-server-2012-2014-and-new-2016-instances-with-sysadmin-privileges/)

(It would depend on NT Authority\System, which may be blocked by the BUILTIN\Administrators explicit deny.)

Comment: And when that does not work either, stop the service and start copying your .mdf and .ldf files to a new instance, while developing grudge and hatred to all DBAs in the world... :)